# Load a page via .load in pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load a PHP page via jQuery. I want it to have a pop-up effect. I tried using the code below, but when the click event is triggered, it seems as if only the CSS from the imported page is being imported. The page content does not appear, but the look changes due to CSS conflicts.

I'd like the page to load and not conflict with the other CSS

```
function previewPop(){
    $(".pop").click(function(){
        $("iframe#preview").load("templates/1.php",

          function(){$("iframe#preview").fadeIn(300); })
    });
};
```

Comment: There are special considerations when trying to run jQuery, especially ajax, in an iframe.

Comment: Right, but the page is on my server, not an external site. Are there still issues?

Comment: You can do it if the iFrame is being loaded from your local site, yes.  But iFrames run by source, not content.  I don't know if you can just load content into it like that.  Is there a reason you're using an iFrame vs a div?

Comment: oh, I see. No, no specific reason for the `<iframe>`. I'll try with a div

Comment: ok, It's now loading the content, but the CSS is still conflicting

Comment: Your php template shouldn't have css in it.  Use the css from the main page to style the content you load into the frame / div

Comment: It has to in this case. The file either displays a preview or generates a PDF. The CSS is needed for both. The preview uses different font families etc... Instead of changing all the markup, this is what I have to work with

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34568/discussion-between-cale-b-and-relentless)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="frame_wrapper">

</div>



$(".pop").click(function(){
 var the_iframe = '<iframe id="my_iframe" src="' + templates/1.php + '" height="500px" width="500px">';
 $('#frame_wrapper').append(the_iframe);
});
```

I hate dealing with iframes, so sometimes it's just easier to create a new one and destroy it as necessary.